# How to run this script onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, forms

I'm sorry to bother you with such a simple question but Ive looked every where and can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for doing what I want to do.

Basically I have a form with a ton of check boxes and want to allow the user to check them all at the same time (or uncheck them all)

I came across this great script

```
    $(function () {
    $('.checkall').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

but when I try to set my input button's onclick event to run the script nothing happens.

```
<input type="button" class="blkbuttonsmall" value="Toggle All/None" onclick="**what-do-i-use-here-to-run?**">
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

***EDIT***

So I tried the two answers last night with no success. I'm not sure if I still am doing something wrong of if there was a communication error on my side. So here's the different things I tried with no success, and a bit more info on how the page is set up.

The check boxes and input button each have their own classes which I am using to style their appearance. They are coded as such before any considerations were given to running this script.

Select All Button

```
<input type="button" class="blkbuttonsmall" value="Toggle All/None">
```

The Check Boxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="X" id="X" class="formcheck">
```

So now taking the suggestions provided last night(thanks again guys for the speedy replies) I tried 
changing the Select All Button's class to both 'blkbuttonsmall checkall' and just 'checkall'. When that didn't work I tried applying the 'checkall' class to some of the checkboxes, removing the 'formcheck' class and adding the 'checkall' class. Still, nothing. This leads me to believe I must not be implementing things correctly, or didn't explain properly in my question the first time.

Here's a few HTML snipets of my code, **before I tried any edits suggested**.

The left div of the form:

```
<div class="formleft">
<br />          
    <form action="">
        <span class="formtext">Check all that apply</span>
<br />
<br />
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $('.checkall').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
    });
    </script>
        <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="logincheck" id="logincheck" class="formcheck"> login
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="assignbreakbusylogoutcheck"  id="assignbreakbusylogoutcheck" class="formcheck"> assignment, break, busy, logout
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="acceptprocesscallscheck" id="acceptprocesscallscheck" class="formcheck"> accept/process tasks, calls
        <br />
</div>
```

... 
The right div of the form

```
<div class="formright">
<br />
<!-- when button is clicked we need to toggle all checks on or off -->
        <input type="button" class="blkbuttonsmall" value="Toggle All/None">
<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="userprofilecheck" id="userprofilecheck" class="formcheck"> user profile
<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="searchcheck" id="searchcheck" class="formcheck"> search
<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="addcheck" id="addcheck" class="formcheck"> add
<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="editcheck" id="editcheck" class="formcheck"> edit
        </fieldset>
     </form>
</div>
```

And just to make sure Im not a ponce who messed up the jquery declaration here's the header of the file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>web portal configurations</title>

       <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-ico">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
```

The jquery file is the latest minified version provided on jquery's site and just uploaded locally to my server.

What am I missing or doing wrong here? I understand the concepts of the previous responses, so the problem has to be something I missed or the implementation. Again, I appreciate any help offered!

Comment: That function requires an element with class `.checkall` to be click but your button's class is `blkbuttonsmall`

Comment: So the check boxes need the class .checkall added to them. The button with the blkbuttonsmall class is the button I want to click to check all the checkboxes.

Right?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to put anything there, you just need to add the class `'checkall'` to your inputs. Thus, you should have something like:

```
<input type="button" class="blkbuttonsmall checkall" value="Toggle All/None">
```

The reason for this is that the jQuery selector `'.checkall'` in `$('.checkall')` finds all elements with the class `'checkall'`, and then attaches the function you specified to it.

Comment: Ah thanks! Ill give that a try later tonight. That certainly explains why no matter what call I put in the onclick event nothing occurs.

Comment: You could expand this to point out jQuery uses CSS selection rules.